# python- download mp3 from youtube

Tags: python, youtube, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to downaload mp3 from a list of videos I have in youtube with Python:
So far I have:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

url='https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLYjSYQBFeM-zQeZFpWeZ_4tnhc3GQWNj8'

page=urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())
todos=soup.findAll("a",{'class':'yt-uix-sessionlink'})
for todo in todos:
            if  len(str(todo.get('href'))) > 1 and 'index' in todo.get('href'):
                dir='https://www.youtube.com' 
                texto=str(todo.get('href'))
                final=texto.find("&list") 
                subtexto=dir+texto[0: final]
                a.append(subtexto)

lista=set(a)
```

So I've got the list of videos. I went to to the url to convert them to mp3

```
url2='http://www.youtube-mp3.org/'
```

and found that I have to paste each one in the 'form' tag:

```
page2=urllib2.urlopen(url2)
soup2 = BeautifulSoup(page2.read())

formu=soup2.find('div', attrs={'id':'form'}).find('input')
```

If I print formu I get:

> ```
> <input autocomplete="off" id="youtube-url" onclick="sAll(this)" type="text" value="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KMU0tzLwhbE"/>
> ```

I thought those libraries might help:

```
import requests
import lxml.html as lh
```

So I tried:

```
form_data={'input':lista[1]}
response = requests.post(url2, data=form_data)
```

But then I have to send 'ENTER' keys and press the button 'Convert video'. Can you give me a hint of how to do this?

Comment: I don't know if you are aware of this but most, if not all videos on youtube are available in audio-only format.

Comment: ok, but anyway, I want to use the lists that I already have.

Comment: That's what I meant: when you download a video, for instance with `youtube-dl`, you can just tell it you want it in audio-only format. No need to go through a third-party website for this.

Comment: I just want to do it as an excercise

Comment: But then I have to send 'ENTER' keys and press the button 'Convert video' ... `Selenium` would do the job

Answer (score 0):

The absolute best way to click a button on a webpage is to use a webdriver, like Selenium.
However, you can simulate the clicking of submit button by invoking the same call as would have been invoked on the click of that button.

In case of youtube-mp3, I saw that it was an XMLHTTPRequest, a get request.

http://www.youtube-mp3.org/a/pushItem/?item=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DuO59tfQ2TbA&r=1476878990281&s=33319

There are two parameters which I don't understand. The r and s. But I found that if we don't change them, the query just works. We can change the item value to anything we want and it would return us with a videoid.

```
r = requests.get("http://www.youtube-mp3.org/a/pushItem/?item=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DuO59tfQ2TbA&r=1476878990281&s=33319")
print r.text
```

This will give you a video id. Use this video id in the next call

http://www.youtube-mp3.org/a/itemInfo/?video_id=uO59tfQ2TbA&ac=www&t=grp&r=1476878991758&s=156841

This will return a json. Use this JSON to get the file.

http://www.youtube-mp3.org/get?video_id=srjPtc7ykiw&ts_create=1476878991&r=MTAuMTA3LjQ3LjI%3D&h2=c9ceec7efc6c61251ce671b5d63cd4c0&s=3278